# Error need help /boot/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod not found

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm really frustrated! I bought me a new laptop a half year ago, with windows 8 pre-installed. Then I installed Ubuntu 13.04 as a dual boot, but after a short time of using my Laptop, software-center couldn't open... so I wanted to reinstall Ubuntu. I inserted the Ubuntu DVD and used "delete Ubuntu and reinstall" (or something like that). When I now reinstalled, I needed to restart, which I did... when I now restart, the laptop shows the ASUS logo, but then only appears a Black screen with a white text that shows:

```
error: '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/normal.mod not found

grub rescue>_
```

I already wanted to boot from the Ubuntu DVD, but I doesn't load the DVD!
what can I type in, to rescue, my data?, I would also delete everything, but I still want to use my Laptop! Please, I need help, please, I would be pleased for every answer!

Comment: How has the live system used for reinstallation been booted (EFI or legacy)?

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

- Try running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) from an emergency disc. This might fix the problem with GRUB, but there's a chance that it won't. If it doesn't work, save the URL that it provides. If the next suggestion also doesn't work, post the URL that Boot Repair gave you, along with any additional observations. The URL will point to a document with partitioning and other configuration details for your computer, which will be helpful in doing further diagnosis of your problem.
- Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and prepare a suitable medium. Try booting with it. If rEFInd lets you boot both Windows and Linux, install the Debian package version of the program from Ubuntu. This will then take over from GRUB 2 as the default boot manager. (It's essentially maintenance-free, unless something else gets in the way or you have a problem with a kernel bug or the like.)