# Need help with Dual boot Win 8.1 & Ubuntu 14.04 on HP Envy j112 tx Notebook

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I bought a new HP notebook with pre-installed Win 8.1. I am trying to dual boot it with Ubuntu 14.04. I have followed the
usual steps, and installed Ubuntu on my system. However, when I boot the system it goes to Win 8 and does not dual boot. 
I was able to access ubuntu in the legacy mode, but had to manually intervene the boot process. To change the legacy mode
I ran boot-repair, as advised on the forum here, with the recommended settings. This is the before and after bootinfo.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7729761/

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7729851/

Now, when I try to boot into Ubuntu from the HDD it goes into grub rescue mode with the error '/boot/grub/
i386-pc/normal.mod not found. 
Which I suppose is bound to happen since grub-pc was replaced to grub-efi in the 
boot repair. 
The problem is that even after the boot repair the system boots into OS manager which by default boots Win 8.
I read here 
[Dual boot Win 8 / Ubuntu loads only Win](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789)

that HP notebooks might be hard-coded to boot only Win 8. Since I am new to linux I'm unable to figure out what to do next and how to work around this problem. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need Help Fixing Grub after Installing Ubuntu 13.04 x64 Alongside Windows 8 on a Lenovo IdeaPad Y400 with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/328673/need-help-fixing-grub-after-installing-ubuntu-13-04-x64-alongside-windows-8-on-a). See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/349123/error-need-help-boot-grub-x86-64-efi-normal-mod-not-found and http://askubuntu.com/questions/325839/file-error-boot-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-trying-to-repair-boot-live-dvd-install

Answer (score 0):

@sd14

I am new to linux too. There are quite a few good tutorial. Do quick google search you will find a few? I have summarized a few that you might find helpful.

- [DUAL boot issues with windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399110/dual-boot-issues-with-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
- [Dual boot with Windows 8.1 on Toshiba Satellite](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418292/dual-boot-with-windows-8-1-on-toshiba-sattelite)

Also give a little bit more detail on what you have done with your outcome. This way you will get a better response from the community.